# Android display unicode characters in TextView

Tags: android, unicode, textview

I am displaying data in a `TextView` that is being retrieved from a remote source. Sometimes that text contains characters that don't display properly in my `TextView`. For example, `&` shows as `&amp;`

I tried:

```
text = Html.fromHtml(text).toString();
```

Then the characters display properly, but all of the text appears on one line, even if it doesn't fit on one line. From there I tried setting `textView.setSingleLine(false);` but it still shows as one line of text.

How can I get this text to show the characters properly and also show as multiple lines when necessary? Other solutions suggest manually putting the characters in a string variable, or displaying the characters programmatically, but since it's text that is pulled from the web that isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

Split your data into separate lines, call `fromHtml` on each and then join them back together.

Comment: Great idea... and I thought about that. But how do I separate it into lines? Line size is going to depend on screen size, and the OS usually handles displaying that properly.

Comment: Oh, I thought you want to preserve Line breaks which are already present in the remote data. In this case, set `android:inputType="textMultiLine"`

Comment: 1) Line breaks aren't in the remote data. It's generally one wall of text, and line breaks are handled by the browser on the web, and are handled by Android in this case... except when I convert it to HTML to handle the unicode characters.

2) It's not an input. It's a TextView. TextView doesn't support inputType.

Comment: post the view and surrounding layout (xml or generating code)